# TinyMCE with jQuery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, validation, tinymce

I am trying to use the [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org) with tinyMce but I am having a small problem.

By default the validation plugin has the following behavior: initially every field is marked as valid and the validation is lazy i.e. the error isn't shown until the user enters a value and moves away from the field. Once a field is marked as invalid, it is eagerly validated which means the validation is done on every key stroke.

I am having difficulty simulating this behavior for the TinyMCE field. If I use the onChange method the validation is always done on focus out. If I use the onKeyDown method, validation is done on every key stroke, even if the user is changing the field for the first time.

Is there some way I can use a combination of onChange and onKeyDown in order to mimic the default behavior of jQuery validation plugin? Here is the code that I currently have:

```
function(ed) {
    ed.onChange.add(function(ed, e) {
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        jQuery('#'+ed.id).valid();
    });
}
```

In case I am not making sense you can read how the validation plugin behaves [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#a-few-things-to-look-out-for-when-playing-around-with-the-demo).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going to have to have a valid state variable

Something like this

```
function(ed) {
    var validState = true;

    ed.onKeyDown.add(function(ed, e) {
        if (validState) {
            return
        }
        else {
            // check if new content is valid
            validState = jQuery('#'+ed.id).valid();
        }
    }

    ed.onChange.add(function(ed, e) {
        validState = jQuery('#'+ed.id).valid();

        if (validState){
            tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        }

    });
}
```

**Note** this is just some sample code. I haven't verified that this will work

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that the .valid() method returned a value.

Comment: @HasanAkhtar Here's the [ref](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid). Also says that the `validate()` method needs to be called on the form before checking it using this method.